# Is there a way to take action, thus execute code, when a iOS application crashes ? Is this possible?

Tags: ios

Is there a way to take action, thus execute code, when an iOS application crashes? Specifically, I would like to save the core data storage. Is this possible? I would say that this is possible since, for example, Firebase has to send information online for making crashlytics work. How can this be achieved? Thanks

Comment: Proper error handling with do/catch, no forced unwrapping etc should be your first defence but once the application has crashed it is no longer running if you know what I mean.

Comment: Then how can Firebase send the current info to crashlytics ? Thanks

Comment: I think it is quite different to handle crashlytics and working with core data as Rob describes in his answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, but it is very difficult, and "save core data storage" would be far too much (and very dangerous, to boot).

Most crashes result from a signal (often SIGSEGV, but also SIGABRT, SIGILL or others), and you can install a signal handler to run code in that case. However, that code must be very, very carefully written because you will be in a special execution state. There are a small number of C functions you are permitted to use (see the man page for `sigaction` for the list). Most notably, you can't allocate memory. Allocating memory in a signal catching function can deadlock the program in a tight spinlock (done that myself when I tried to write my own crash handler in my more naive days; it's really bad).

The way that crash handlers like Crashlytics do it is that they do as little as possible during the signal handler, mostly just writing the stack trace to storage (using pre-allocated buffers). When you restart, they see that there's an unhandled stack trace from a previous run, and *then* they do all the complicated stuff like uploading it to a server, or displaying UI, or whatever.

But even if you could write to Core Data in the middle of a signal handler, you would never want to do that. During a signal handler, the system is in an undefined state. Various invariants may not currently hold (such as whether the object graph is consistent). The fact that you're crashing this way indicates that something illegal has happened. The last thing you should do in that state is take data that is highly untrustworthy and overwrite the good data on disk.

Comment: Thanks a lot Rob for taking the time for such a detailed explanation. Big thanks.

Comment: Rob as always with the most useful info